# Is there a way to replace all negative values in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i have large multilevel JSON (approx 3 - 20 MB) with data from my smartwatch. Their firmware sometimes stores a bad (negative) value, which I would need to filter out before importing into the application (NodeJS). All values that are negative in JSON (there can be one to several thousand in one package), I would need to replace with zero regardless of their value.

This is what the part with the bad data looks like (sometimes only some of the items are negative):

```
"11" : {
    "bleid": "D7:6C:7A:0C:A8:7B",
    "calorie": "-15", // HERE
    "date": "2020-06-07",
    "distance": -323", // HERE
    "month": "",
    "startime": "11:00",
    "step": "-522", // HERE
    "time": "",
    "type": "mtkbracelet"
},
```

Did someone please solve a similar problem?

Comment: Don't put images.

Comment: Just iterate over the object and make the appropriate changes? You can also transform the values as you parse the JSON via a reviver function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the tip, this could be exactly it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a JSON, most likely you would have to `parse` in an actual object before doing anything useful (either the smartwatch sending you via socket or you read it as file, in both case it's a string); you could then use the second parameter of `parse` method, a `reviver` callback, to map the negative number into a different value. Something like:

```
let s = "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":-1,\"baz\":10},\"qux\":-1}";
let o = JSON.parse(s, (key, value) => value < 0 ? 0 : value);

console.log(o); // {foo: {bar: 0, baz: 10}, qux: 0}
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thank you, I already have it! I didn't know about this option at JSON.parse, its like a magic!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the JSON to a string and then iterate through it replacing all negative numbers using a regular expression, then parse the string back to JSON.

```
let json = {} // Your json

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(json)
let reformat = jsonString.replace(/(?<=")-[0-9]*(?=")/g, '0')

return JSON.parse(reformat)
```

Regular expression explenation:

`(?<=")` - Positive lookbehind, which looks for `"`

`-[0-9]*` - String must start with `-`, then contain only numbers. Also `*` means the number can be any length

`(?=")` - Positive lookahead, which looks for `"`

`g` - Global, meaning it will look for all occurances

Comment: JSON, by definition, is already textual data. `{}` in `let json = {}` is an object, not JSON.